# Can polar coordinates always be used to calculate a limit in a multivariable function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Are polar coordinates always a viable way to calculate the limit of a multivariable function?

In lecture, it appeared as if converting a function into polar coordinates and then checking the limit as *r* approaches 0 would be a foolproof way to determine a limit. However, after doing some online reading it appears as if it is not a viable method when the function is not "independently bound of theta". Could someone please explain this to me? I am having difficulty understanding this concept.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$, then the polar substitution makes the denominator $r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r^2$.

If your function is $\frac{x}{x^2+2y^2}$, then the polar substitution makes the denominator $r^2(\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta)$, from which you can't just eliminate $\theta$ the same way.

Comment: vadim, wouldn't the second function $x/(x^2)+2y^2$ with the denominator you provided in polar form also be "independently bound" of theta, since setting $r=o$ would make the whole denominator 0, regardless of theta, meaning it would be undefined?

Comment: We do not set $r=0$, we take a limit as $r\to 0$.